# WordPress: How to link post to particular page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new in WordPress and trying to do the following:

I have main menu with some options (Home, File, Edit, View...). I also want to have posts. The posts can belong to different categories that match the menu options. The only last post should be displayed on Home page (Home menu option). Other older posts should be on pages under appropriate menu options.

I've searched the internet but not found the right solution.

Can I do that with WordPress?

I don't know PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your question properly. As you said you don't know PHP so it will be little difficult  but you can make it by custom template or editing your index page of template. 
Or if you want to show 1 post(last) at your website without any php, you can go to your Dashboard->Setting->Reading and make "Blog pages show at most" from 10 to 1. But the problem is your website will show like blog. If you are using "Twenty Twelve" let me know i will make it for you.

Comment: Ok. I've got what you wrote. But, how can I send my posts after I wrote them to be under particular menu option?

Comment: Go to your menu option and You can create menu for different pages and category. And you can make custom menu link by "custom link". Add title as level and (your post link) as url.

Comment: I've tried it and it works. But only if we have 1 post. What if we have more posts of the same category and want to place them all under the appropriate menu option?

Comment: You can use tag or category. Then make a menu with that tag or category.